How to add a .transform Nystroem method to project new observations into an existing space? (Diffusion Maps in Python)
I am copying over some code from mapalign for calculating diffusion maps using the sklearn api.  Currently, there is no .transform method so I've forked the repo and I'm trying to add it myself but I'm having trouble.
Essentially, I'm looking for the following usage where X and Y are tabular (N, m) have the same number of columns (m):
model = DiffusionMapEmbedding()

#model.fit(X)
#X_embedding = model.transform(X)
X_embedding = model.fit_transform(X)

Y_embedding = model.transform(Y)

Here's the code from mapalign for the DiffusionMapEmbedding class:
from __future__ import annotations
import os,sys,gzip,pickle,warnings
from typing import TypeVar
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
import scipy.sparse as sps
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
from sklearn.utils import check_array, check_random_state
from sklearn.manifold._spectral_embedding import _graph_is_connected
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel

def compute_affinity(X, method='markov', eps=None, metric='euclidean'):
    """Compute the similarity or affinity matrix between the samples in X

    :param X: A set of samples with number of rows > 1
    :param method: 'markov' or 'cauchy' kernel (default: markov)
    :param eps: scaling factor for kernel
    :param metric: metric to compute pairwise distances
    :return: a similarity matrix

    >>> X = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,9,4,4]])
    >>> np.allclose(compute_affinity(X, eps=1e3), [[1., 0.96367614], [ 0.96367614, 1.]])
    True

    >>> X = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,9,4,4]])
    >>> np.allclose(compute_affinity(X, 'cauchy', eps=1e3), [[0.001,  0.00096432], [ 0.00096432, 0.001 ]])
    True
    """
    D = squareform(pdist(X, metric=metric))
    if eps is None:
        k = int(max(2, np.round(D.shape[0] * 0.01)))
        eps = 2 * np.median(np.sort(D, axis=0)[k+1, :])**2
    if method == 'markov':
        affinity_matrix = np.exp(-(D * D) / eps)
    elif method == 'cauchy':
        affinity_matrix = 1./(D * D + eps)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown method: {}".format(method))
    return affinity_matrix


def compute_diffusion_map(L, alpha=0.5, n_components=None, diffusion_time=0,
                          skip_checks=False, overwrite=False,
                          eigen_solver="eigs", return_result=False):
    """
    Original Source:
    https://github.com/satra/mapalign/blob/master/mapalign/embed.py

    Compute the diffusion maps of a symmetric similarity matrix

        L : matrix N x N
           L is symmetric and L(x, y) >= 0

        alpha: float [0, 1]
            Setting alpha=1 and the diffusion operator approximates the
            Laplace-Beltrami operator. We then recover the Riemannian geometry
            of the data set regardless of the distribution of the points. To
            describe the long-term behavior of the point distribution of a
            system of stochastic differential equations, we can use alpha=0.5
            and the resulting Markov chain approximates the Fokker-Planck
            diffusion. With alpha=0, it reduces to the classical graph Laplacian
            normalization.

        n_components: int
            The number of diffusion map components to return. Due to the
            spectrum decay of the eigenvalues, only a few terms are necessary to
            achieve a given relative accuracy in the sum M^t.

        diffusion_time: float >= 0
            use the diffusion_time (t) step transition matrix M^t

            t not only serves as a time parameter, but also has the dual role of
            scale parameter. One of the main ideas of diffusion framework is
            that running the chain forward in time (taking larger and larger
            powers of M) reveals the geometric structure of X at larger and
            larger scales (the diffusion process).

            t = 0 empirically provides a reasonable balance from a clustering
            perspective. Specifically, the notion of a cluster in the data set
            is quantified as a region in which the probability of escaping this
            region is low (within a certain time t).

        skip_checks: bool
            Avoid expensive pre-checks on input data. The caller has to make
            sure that input data is valid or results will be undefined.

        overwrite: bool
            Optimize memory usage by re-using input matrix L as scratch space.

        References
        ----------

        [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_map
        [2] Coifman, R.R.; S. Lafon. (2006). "Diffusion maps". Applied and
        Computational Harmonic Analysis 21: 5-30. doi:10.1016/j.acha.2006.04.006
    """



    if isinstance(eigen_solver, str):
        assert eigen_solver in {"eigs", "eigsh"}, "eigen_solver must either be a string: [eigs, eigsh] or a callable: {} [type:{}]".format(eigen_solver, type(eigen_solver))
        if eigen_solver == "eigs":
            eigen_solver = sps.linalg.eigs
        if  eigen_solver == "eigsh":
            eigen_solver = sps.linalg.eigsh
    assert hasattr(eigen_solver, "__call__"), "eigen_solver must either be a string: [eigs, eigsh] or a callable: {} [type:{}]".format(eigen_solver, type(eigen_solver))

    use_sparse = False
    if sps.issparse(L):
        use_sparse = True

    if not skip_checks:
        if not _graph_is_connected(L):
            raise ValueError('Graph is disconnected')

    ndim = L.shape[0]
    if overwrite:
        L_alpha = L
    else:
        L_alpha = L.copy()

    if alpha > 0:
        # Step 2
        d = np.array(L_alpha.sum(axis=1)).flatten()
        d_alpha = np.power(d, -alpha)
        if use_sparse:
            L_alpha.data *= d_alpha[L_alpha.indices]
            L_alpha = sps.csr_matrix(L_alpha.transpose().toarray())
            L_alpha.data *= d_alpha[L_alpha.indices]
            L_alpha = sps.csr_matrix(L_alpha.transpose().toarray())
        else:
            L_alpha = d_alpha[:, np.newaxis] * L_alpha 
            L_alpha = L_alpha * d_alpha[np.newaxis, :]

    # Step 3
    d_alpha = np.power(np.array(L_alpha.sum(axis=1)).flatten(), -1)
    if use_sparse:
        L_alpha.data *= d_alpha[L_alpha.indices]
    else:
        L_alpha = d_alpha[:, np.newaxis] * L_alpha

    M = L_alpha

    # Step 4
    if n_components is not None:
        lambdas, vectors = eigen_solver(M, k=n_components + 1)
    else:
        lambdas, vectors = eigen_solver(M, k=max(2, int(np.sqrt(ndim))))
    del M

    if eigen_solver == sps.linalg.eigsh:
        lambdas = lambdas[::-1]
        vectors = vectors[:, ::-1]
    else:
        lambdas = np.real(lambdas)
        vectors = np.real(vectors)
        lambda_idx = np.argsort(lambdas)[::-1]
        lambdas = lambdas[lambda_idx]
        vectors = vectors[:, lambda_idx]

    return _step_5(lambdas, vectors, ndim, n_components, diffusion_time)


def _step_5(lambdas, vectors, ndim, n_components, diffusion_time):
    """
    Original Source:
    https://github.com/satra/mapalign/blob/master/mapalign/embed.py

    This is a helper function for diffusion map computation.

    The lambdas have been sorted in decreasing order.
    The vectors are ordered according to lambdas.

    """
    psi = vectors/vectors[:, [0]]
    diffusion_times = diffusion_time
    if diffusion_time == 0:
        diffusion_times = np.exp(1. -  np.log(1 - lambdas[1:])/np.log(lambdas[1:]))
        lambdas = lambdas[1:] / (1 - lambdas[1:])
    else:
        lambdas = lambdas[1:] ** float(diffusion_time)
    lambda_ratio = lambdas/lambdas[0]
    threshold = max(0.05, lambda_ratio[-1])

    n_components_auto = np.amax(np.nonzero(lambda_ratio > threshold)[0])
    n_components_auto = min(n_components_auto, ndim)
    if n_components is None:
        n_components = n_components_auto
    embedding = psi[:, 1:(n_components + 1)] * lambdas[:n_components][None, :]

    result = dict(lambdas=lambdas, vectors=vectors,
                    n_components=n_components, diffusion_times=diffusion_times,
                    n_components_auto=n_components_auto, embedding=embedding)
    return result



def compute_diffusion_map_psd(
        X, alpha=0.5, n_components=None, diffusion_time=0):
    """
    Original Source:
    https://github.com/satra/mapalign/blob/master/mapalign/embed.py

    This variant requires L to be dense, positive semidefinite and entrywise
    positive with decomposition L = dot(X, X.T).

    """

    # Redefine X such that L is normalized in a way that is analogous
    # to a generalization of the normalized Laplacian.
    d = X.dot(X.sum(axis=0)) ** (-alpha)
    X = X * d[:, np.newaxis]

    # Decompose M = D^-1 X X^T
    # This is like
    # M = D^-1/2 D^-1/2 X (D^-1/2 X).T D^1/2
    # Substituting U = D^-1/2 X we have
    # M = D^-1/2 U U.T D^1/2
    # which is a diagonal change of basis of U U.T
    # which itself can be decomposed using svd.
    d = np.sqrt(X.dot(X.sum(axis=0)))
    U = X / d[:, np.newaxis]

    if n_components is not None:
        u, s, vh = sps.linalg.svds(U, k=n_components+1, return_singular_vectors=True)
    else:
        k = max(2, int(np.sqrt(ndim)))
        u, s, vh = sps.linalg.svds(U, k=k, return_singular_vectors=True)

    # restore the basis and the arbitrary norm of 1
    u = u / d[:, np.newaxis]
    u = u / np.linalg.norm(u, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    lambdas = s*s
    vectors = u

    # sort the lambdas in decreasing order and reorder vectors accordingly
    lambda_idx = np.argsort(lambdas)[::-1]
    lambdas = lambdas[lambda_idx]
    vectors = vectors[:, lambda_idx]

    return _step_5(lambdas, vectors, X.shape[0], n_components, diffusion_time)

class DiffusionMapEmbedding(BaseEstimator):
    """
    Original Source:
    https://github.com/satra/mapalign/blob/master/mapalign/embed.py

    Diffusion map embedding for non-linear dimensionality reduction.

    Forms an affinity matrix given by the specified function and
    applies spectral decomposition to the corresponding graph laplacian.
    The resulting transformation is given by the value of the
    eigenvectors for each data point.

    Note : Laplacian Eigenmaps is the actual algorithm implemented here.

    Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <spectral_embedding>`.

    Parameters
    ----------

    diffusion_time : float
        Determines the scaling of the eigenvalues of the Laplacian

    alpha : float, optional, default: 0.5
        Setting alpha=1 and the diffusion operator approximates the
        Laplace-Beltrami operator. We then recover the Riemannian geometry
        of the data set regardless of the distribution of the points. To
        describe the long-term behavior of the point distribution of a
        system of stochastic differential equations, we can use alpha=0.5
        and the resulting Markov chain approximates the Fokker-Planck
        diffusion. With alpha=0, it reduces to the classical graph Laplacian
        normalization.

    n_components : integer, default: 2
        The dimension of the projected subspace.

    eigen_solver : {None, 'eigs' or 'eigsh'}
        The eigenvalue decomposition strategy to use.

    random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional, default: None
        A pseudo random number generator used for the initialization of the
        lobpcg eigenvectors.  If int, random_state is the seed used by the
        random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the
        random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the
        RandomState instance used by `np.random`. Used when ``solver`` ==
        'amg'.

    affinity : string or callable, default : "nearest_neighbors"
        How to construct the affinity matrix.
         - 'nearest_neighbors' : construct affinity matrix by knn graph
         - 'rbf' : construct affinity matrix by rbf kernel
         - 'markov': construct affinity matrix by Markov kernel
         - 'cauchy': construct affinity matrix by Cauchy kernel
         - 'precomputed' : interpret X as precomputed affinity matrix
         - callable : use passed in function as affinity
           the function takes in data matrix (n_samples, n_features)
           and return affinity matrix (n_samples, n_samples).

    gamma : float, optional
        Kernel coefficient for pairwise distance (rbf, markov, cauchy)

    metric : string, optional
        Metric for scipy pdist function used to compute pairwise distances
        for markov and cauchy kernels

    n_neighbors : int, default : max(n_samples/10 , 1)
        Number of nearest neighbors for nearest_neighbors graph building.

    use_variant : boolean, default : False
        Use a variant requires L to be dense, positive semidefinite and
        entrywise positive with decomposition L = dot(X, X.T).

    n_jobs : int, optional (default = 1)
        The number of parallel jobs to run.
        If ``-1``, then the number of jobs is set to the number of CPU cores.

    Attributes
    ----------

    embedding_ : array, shape = (n_samples, n_components)
        Spectral embedding of the training matrix.

    affinity_matrix_ : array, shape = (n_samples, n_samples)
        Affinity_matrix constructed from samples or precomputed.

    References
    ----------

    - Lafon, Stephane, and Ann B. Lee. "Diffusion maps and coarse-graining: A
      unified framework for dimensionality reduction, graph partitioning, and
      data set parameterization." Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence,
      IEEE Transactions on 28.9 (2006): 1393-1403.
      https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2006.184

    - Coifman, Ronald R., and Stephane Lafon. Diffusion maps. Applied and
      Computational Harmonic Analysis 21.1 (2006): 5-30.
      https://doi.org/10.1016/j.acha.2006.04.006

    """

    def __init__(self, diffusion_time=0, alpha=0.5, n_components=2,
                 affinity="nearest_neighbors", gamma=None,
                 metric='euclidean', random_state=None, eigen_solver="eigs",
                 n_neighbors=None, use_variant=False, n_jobs=1):
        self.diffusion_time = diffusion_time
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.affinity = affinity
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.metric = metric
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.eigen_solver = eigen_solver
        self.n_neighbors = n_neighbors
        self.use_variant = use_variant
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs

    @property
    def _pairwise(self):
        return self.affinity == "precomputed"

    def _get_affinity_matrix(self, X, Y=None):
        """Calculate the affinity matrix from data
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.

            If affinity is "precomputed"
            X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_samples),
            Interpret X as precomputed adjacency graph computed from
            samples.

        Returns
        -------
        affinity_matrix, shape (n_samples, n_samples)
        """
        if self.affinity == 'precomputed':
            self.affinity_matrix_ = X
            return self.affinity_matrix_
        if self.affinity == 'nearest_neighbors':
            if sps.issparse(X):
                warnings.warn("Nearest neighbors affinity currently does "
                              "not support sparse input, falling back to "
                              "rbf affinity")
                self.affinity = "rbf"
            else:
                self.n_neighbors_ = (self.n_neighbors
                                     if self.n_neighbors is not None
                                     else max(int(X.shape[0] / 10), 1))
                self.affinity_matrix_ = kneighbors_graph(X, self.n_neighbors_,
                                                         include_self=True,
                                                         n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
                # currently only symmetric affinity_matrix supported
                self.affinity_matrix_ = 0.5 * (self.affinity_matrix_ +
                                               self.affinity_matrix_.T)
                return self.affinity_matrix_
        if self.affinity == 'rbf':
            self.gamma_ = (self.gamma
                           if self.gamma is not None else 1.0 / X.shape[1])
            self.affinity_matrix_ = rbf_kernel(X, gamma=self.gamma_)
            return self.affinity_matrix_
        if self.affinity in ['markov', 'cauchy']:
            self.affinity_matrix_ = compute_affinity(X,
                                                     method=self.affinity,
                                                     eps=self.gamma,
                                                     metric=self.metric)
            return self.affinity_matrix_
        self.affinity_matrix_ = self.affinity(X)
        return self.affinity_matrix_

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """Fit the model from data in X.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.

            If affinity is "precomputed"
            X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_samples),
            Interpret X as precomputed adjacency graph computed from
            samples.

        Returns
        -------
        self : object
            Returns the instance itself.
        """

        X = check_array(X, ensure_min_samples=2, estimator=self)

        random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
        if isinstance(self.affinity, (str,)):
            if self.affinity not in set(("nearest_neighbors", "rbf",
                                         "markov", "cauchy",
                                         "precomputed")):
                raise ValueError(("%s is not a valid affinity. Expected "
                                  "'precomputed', 'rbf', 'nearest_neighbors' "
                                  "or a callable.") % self.affinity)
        elif not callable(self.affinity):
            raise ValueError(("'affinity' is expected to be an affinity "
                              "name or a callable. Got: %s") % self.affinity)

        affinity_matrix = self._get_affinity_matrix(X)
        if self.use_variant:
            result = compute_diffusion_map_psd(affinity_matrix,
                                                        alpha=self.alpha,
                                                        n_components=self.n_components,
                                                        diffusion_time=self.diffusion_time)
        else:
            result = compute_diffusion_map(affinity_matrix,
                                                    alpha=self.alpha,
                                                    n_components=self.n_components,
                                                    diffusion_time=self.diffusion_time,
                                                    eigen_solver=self.eigen_solver)
            
        for k in ["lambdas", "vectors", "diffusion_times", "embedding"]:
            v = result[k]
            setattr(self, "{}_".format(k), v)
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        """Fit the model from data in X and transform X.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.

            If affinity is "precomputed"
            X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_samples),
            Interpret X as precomputed adjacency graph computed from
            samples.

        Returns
        -------
        X_new : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)
        """
        self.fit(X)
        return self.embedding_

Here's a test dataset:
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, targets = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=2, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=0)
X, Y, x_targets, y_targets = train_test_split(X, targets, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

model = DiffusionMapEmbedding(random_state=0)
model.fit(X)
plt.scatter(model.embedding_[:,0], model.embedding_[:,1], c=x_targets, edgecolor="black", linewidths=0.5)


I've been trying to use the eigenvectors to transform new data but it's not as straightforward as I had hoped. Step 5 seems to be the most relevant section here but it looks like I'll need to run the eigensolver for the new data as well which would basically just be rerunning the algorithm with the new dataset (and refitting the model):
    psi = vectors/vectors[:, [0]]
    diffusion_times = diffusion_time
    if diffusion_time == 0:
        diffusion_times = np.exp(1. -  np.log(1 - lambdas[1:])/np.log(lambdas[1:]))
        lambdas = lambdas[1:] / (1 - lambdas[1:])
    else:
        lambdas = lambdas[1:] ** float(diffusion_time)
...
    embedding = psi[:, 1:(n_components + 1)] * lambdas[:n_components][None, :]

pyDiffMap has an implementation for Nystroem out-of-sample extensions used to calculate the values of the diffusion coordinates at each given point..  The backend implementations of the algorithms are different so I'm not sure if I can just port this method over.  pyDiffMap also implements a power-like method but this is not the default so the Nystroem is preferred unless you can demonstrate that this approach is better for the map align implementation.
Can someone help me figure out how to calculate diffusion coordinates for out-of-sample  data either using the Nystroem method another one that is appropriate? That is, implementing a .transform method for this class.
